# Why is firebase messaging topic subscription not working on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

The app is not subscribing to any topic on iOS devices. There is no issue with Android devices.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Create a new ionic project (6/7).
Add Capacitor 5 (iOS).
Complete the Ionic Post Notification setup steps.
Subscribe to a topic using capacitor-community/fcm.
Expected behavior
The app should subscribe to the topics on iOS just like Android.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActionPerformed, PushNotificationSchema, PushNotifications, Token } from '@capacitor/push-notifications';
import { Preferences } from '@capacitor/preferences';
import { FCM } from '@capacitor-community/fcm';

interface SubscriptionPreferences {
 [key: string]: boolean;
}


@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

 subscriptionPreferences: SubscriptionPreferences = {};
 topics = ['Announcements', 'Calendar', 'Upcoming-Events', 'Block-Rotation', 'Clubs', 'Sports', 'Cafeteria', 'Contests', 'University-Advising', 'New-Student-Help', 'Parent-Info', 'Staff-Directory', 'ios'];

 constructor(private router: Router) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   console.log('Initializing HomePage');

   PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(result => {
     if (result.receive === 'granted') {
       // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
       PushNotifications.register();
     } else {
       // Show some error
     }
   });


   Preferences.get({ key: 'firstTimeOpen' }).then(result => {
     const isFirstTimeOpen = result.value;

     if (isFirstTimeOpen === null || isFirstTimeOpen === 'true') {
       this.topics.forEach(topic => {
         FCM.subscribeTo({ topic: topic })
           .then(() => {
             console.log(`Subscribed to topic ${topic}`);
             this.subscriptionPreferences[topic] = true;
             Preferences.set({ key: 'firstTimeOpen', value: 'true' });
           })
           .catch((error) => {
             Preferences.set({ key: 'firstTimeOpen', value: 'false' });
           });
       });

       this.subscriptionPreferences = this.topics.reduce((acc: SubscriptionPreferences, topic: string) => {
         acc[topic] = true;
         return acc;
       }, {});

       Preferences.set({ key: 'subscriptionPreferences', value: JSON.stringify(this.subscriptionPreferences) });
     } 
      Preferences.get({ key: 'subscriptionPreferences' }).then(result => {
        const preferencesValue = result.value;
        this.subscriptionPreferences = preferencesValue ? JSON.parse(preferencesValue) : {};
       });
       console.log(this.subscriptionPreferences)
     
   });

   PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: Token) => {
     console.log('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
   });

   PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', (error: any) => {
     console.log('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
   });

   PushNotifications.addListener(
     'pushNotificationReceived',
     (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
       alert('Notification received: ' + notification.title + '\n' + notification.body);
     },
   );

   PushNotifications.addListener(
     'pushNotificationActionPerformed',
     (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
       console.log('Push action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));

       if (notification.notification) {
         const notificationData = notification.notification.data;
         if (notificationData && notificationData.page) {
           this.router.navigateByUrl(notificationData.page);
         }
       }
     },
   );
 }

}
```